# Binding and Chosen dropdown plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, jquery-chosen, coldfusion-11

I found and used [Ben Forta's nice tutorial for related selects](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/31/ColdFusion-Ajax-Tutorial-2-Related-Selects).  In the first select, the user chooses a species. In the second select a list of chemicals is populated.  The second select is multiple select.

I'm now attempting to use the [Chosen jQuery plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).  It works fine on other selects I've tried, but when I try it with related selects it's not working. Something with binding perhaps?

```
Select Species:
    <cfform name="mainform" method="Post" action="organism.cfm">
    <cfselect name="SpeciesID" class="chosen-select"
         bind="cfc:species.getSpecies()" bindonload="true"></cfselect>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="chosen.jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('cfselect').chosen()});
</script>

Select a chemical:
    <cfselect name="AnalyteID" multiple="yes" required="Yes" size="5"    
        class="chosen-select" message="Please choose a chemical" 
        bind="cfc:species.getChemName({SpeciesID})" 
   </cfselect>
```

The CFC

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

<cfset THIS.dsn="MyDatabase">

<!--- Get array of species --->
<cffunction name="getSpecies" access="remote" returnType="array">
    <!--- Define variables --->
    <cfset var data="">
    <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
    <cfset var i=0>

    <!--- Get genus species data --->
    <cfquery name="data" datasource="#THIS.dsn#">
    SELECT DISTINCT SpeciesID, GenusSpecies
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY GenusSpecies
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Convert results to array --->
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
        <cfset result[i][1]=data.SpeciesID[i]>
        <cfset result[i][2]=data.GenusSpecies[i]>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>

<!--- Get analyte sorted by genus species --->
<cffunction name="getChemName" access="remote" returnType="array">
<cfargument name="SpeciesID" type="numeric" required="true">

    <!--- Define variables --->
    <cfset var data="">
    <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
    <cfset var i=0>

    <!--- Get analytes --->
    <cfquery name="data" datasource="#THIS.dsn#">
    SELECT DISTINCT analyteID, ChemName
    FROM Table2
    WHERE SpeciesID = #ARGUMENTS.SpeciesID#
    ORDER BY ChemName
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Convert results to array --->
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
        <cfset result[i][1]=data.analyteID[i]>
        <cfset result[i][2]=data.ChemName[i]>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Maybe another plugin will meet my needs better.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Could you post a link to the tutorial you mentioned?

Comment: http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/31/ColdFusion-Ajax-Tutorial-2-Related-Selects

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"? Without knowing more, it could be because the code is mixing two different JS libraries - jQuery and ExtJS, which can cause problems in some cases.  May want to stick with one or the other.

Comment: Posted the CFC.  I'm using the files created by Chosen.  It may be they are using the two libraries.  I'm looking for a means to an end with this plugin.  I was able to get this to work with a cfselect but when I bind a cfc it will not work.

Comment: @user2734498 - They are definitely separate libraries. Guess it is not surprising there are issues since the libs use different event models. Why not just use jQuery for everything instead of trying to mix and match? Side note, the linked article is from 2007. While it was valid at the time, later versions support a more direct method of binding. That said, the CF Ajax libs are usually several versions old, change with CF releases (breaking custom code) and the features are notoriously quirky IMO. You might take this as an opportunity to switch to jQuery for greater control and stability.

Comment: First of all, you're trying to apply this library to a ColdFusion tag, not the rendered HTML: `$('cfselect').chosen()});`. Give that `select` and ID the same value as the name, then use `$('#AnalyteID).chosen()`.

Comment: Thank you Leigh and Adrian.  When I created an ID this helped render the appearance of the dropdown but still no data.  If I switch to jQuery where is a good place to start?

Comment: *still no data* Start by taking a look at your javascript console to see what is happening and if there are any errors. I am not familiar with that plugin, but would not be at all surprised if the two are conflicting somehow.  Also, start with a single cfc before throwing the "related" aspect into the mix. As far as jQuery,  it is a common need, so there are plenty of articles on the topic. Do a search on something like "jQuery populate select list", "jQuery related select lists", "jquery Chosen populate list". articles on the topic.